# How to pass default state for React global store provider from Laravel Blade?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade, react-context

I have set up a global storage for my App, using React Context API like this:

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <SettingsProvider>
            <Items />
        </SettingsProvider>
      );
   }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And mu provider looks something like this:

```
const defaultState = {test:'test'}

function SettingsProvider({children}) {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(settingsReducer, defaultState);

    return (
        <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </SettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Everything is working as expected. But now I would like to pass defaultState to SettingsProvider from Laravel rather than defining it in my javascript, using something like this:

```
<div id="app" defaultstate="{{$state}}"></div>
```

But I haven't figured out, how to access those values from my SettingsProvider... How could I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React doesn't know about HTML attributes. You need to pass the `defaultState` attribute in your Blade template as props to your `App` component then pass down the prop to `SettingsProvider` component.

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <SettingsProvider defaultState={this.props.defaultState}>
            <Items />
        </SettingsProvider>
      );
   }
}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    // find element by id
    const element = document.getElementById('app')

    // Get element's defaultState attribute
    const defaultState = element.getAttribute('defaultState')

    // render element
    render(<App defaultState={defaultState} />, element);
}
```

**SettingsProvider.jsx**

```
const initialState = {test:'test'}

function SettingsProvider({children, defaultState}) {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        settingsReducer,
        //This will override initialState entries with the values you passed via Blade
        {
            ...initialState,
            ...defaultState
        }
    );

    return (
        <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </SettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```